# ¿Porque no puedo ocultar una etiqueta <li>, jquery?

Tags: jquery

De esta forma tengo un tab con su lista:

```
<div id="formaentregaPedido" class="tab">
                <div class="content-block-title" style="font-size: 16px;">Selecciona la forma de entrega de tu pedido</div>
                <div class="list-block no-hairlines no-hairlines-between">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="2">
                                <span class="item-media">
                                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="item-title">Recoger en Centro de Negocio</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1" checked>
                                <span class="item-media">
                                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="item-title">Envío a Domicilio Normal</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li id="sucursalesCorreos" class="sucursalesCorreos">
                            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1">
                                <span class="item-media">
                                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="item-title">Entregar en Sucursal de Correos</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="content-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <span class="col-50 button-icon-ant" data-icon="&#xf053;">
                            <button id="ant-4" class="">Anterior</button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="col-50 button-icon" data-icon="&#xf054;">
                            <button id="btn-4" class="">Siguiente</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y en esta condición debo ocultar el `<li>` con `id="sucursalesCorreos"`

```
if (localStorage.getItem("TipoSocio") == "Afiliado") {
        myApp.showTab("#formaentregaPedido", true);
        $('.sucursalesCorreos').hide();//Este no lo oculta
        $('.button-icon-ant').hide();//Este si lo oculta
    }
    else{
        myApp.showTab("#taba", true);
    }
```

El problema que veo que la etiqueta que tiene la clase `button-icon-ant` si la oculta correctamente, pero la clase `sucursalesCorreos`, no.

Revisando en la consola del navegador veo que a la etiqueta donde se encuentra la clase `button-icon-ant` efectivamente le agrega `style="display: none;"` pero donde se encuentra la clase `sucursalesCorreos` le agrega esto:

```
style="display: list-item;"
```

no entiendo a que se deba.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas con algo más específico como el `id`, ya que lo tiene?: `$('#sucursalesCorreos').hide();`

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa forma, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Es raro, yo lo pruebo fuera del `if` y me funciona incluso así: `$('.sucursalesCorreos').hide();` ¿no será que ese `if` no se cumple realmente? Prueba fuera del if. Puede que lo del botón funcione porque se oculta desde otra parte del código. O pon un alert para ver si entra ahí: `if (localStorage.getItem("TipoSocio") == "Afiliado") {  alert("sí ha entrado!");  //... resto del código }`

Comment: El realidad si entra, ya que la otra clase que tengo con hide(), si lo oculta.

Comment: Como te digo, puede que se oculten por otro motivo. Prueba poniendo un `alert` dentro del `if` para estar seguro que sí entra. No des nada por supuesto en programación, hay que depurarlo todo. Yo lo he probado sin el `if`   y funciona.

Comment: Realice la prueba con el alert y si entra al if.

Comment: Pues no sé qué decirte. ¿Ese es todo el código? ¿Tu librería jQuery está actualizada? Yo he copiado estas dos líneas sin más `$('.sucursalesCorreos').hide();//Este no lo oculta
        $('.button-icon-ant').hide();//Este si lo oculta`
, he pegado el HTML completo en el code snippet  y ambas cosas se ocultan.

Comment: podrías revisar una nueva descripción que agregue a la pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede estar ocurriendo un escenario que no contemplas: ¿Y si se oculta pero acto seguido se vuelve a mostrar? Yo sustituiría el alert de prueba por un `debugger;` justo tras ocultarlo para ver si display está en hidden o no. Quizá tengas una línea que se ejecuta posteriormente que haga un `show()` de ese elemento

Answer (score 1):

prueba con esto, asignarle un valor css al elemento

```
$("#sucursalesCorreos").css('visibility','hidden');
```

Comment: eventualmente podes probar también `$("sucursalesCorreos").css("display", "none");`